# Why is my attempt to fully qualify an MDX calculated member failing? (Mondrian)

Tags: mdx, pentaho, mondrian

This is Pentaho 3.8 CE which I think comes with Mondrian 3.5

This MDX produces a result:

```
WITH MEMBER [Items].[ItemType].[NonSales] as
[Items].[ItemType].[Deposit] + [Items].[ItemType].[Gift_Voucher]
SELECT 
{[Items].[NonSales]} ON COLUMNS,
[Measures].[AmtPaidExclGST] on rows
FROM [sales]
```

(the Dimension is Items. It has one Hierarchy, unnamed, and one level called ItemType.)

However, this doesn't:

```
WITH MEMBER [Items].[ItemType].[NonSales] as
[Items].[ItemType].[Deposit] + [Items].[ItemType].[Gift_Voucher]
SELECT 
{[Items].[ItemType].[NonSales]} ON COLUMNS,
[Measures].[AmtPaidExclGST] on rows
FROM [sales]
```

The difference is that successful Select Row uses a less-qualified version of the name of the calculated member. 
My reading of the MDX documentation indicates that a fully qualified member name should work. I expect both queries to produce the same result.

It does work for a real member. This works.

```
SELECT 
{[Items].[ItemType].[Deposit]} ON COLUMNS,
[Measures].[AmtPaidExclGST] on rows
FROM [sales]
```

I'm new to MDX and this is driving my crazy because I doubt my understanding of how to write member names.

Comment: Actually, I see in this example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146017.aspx 
the Microsoft first writes "In the syntax for the WITH keyword, the Member_Identifier value is the fully qualified name of the calculated member. This fully qualified name includes the dimension or level to which the calculated member is associated."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some old version of mondrian does not allow you to add member to level other than the root level (example of a root level member is ALL in some dimension). Possibly mondrian is adding calculated member (you can query using the dimension) but not able to associate to level (your query using [query 2]).

Thanks